# receiving a specific data from HTML, python, web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I' like to receive a specific data from such HTML file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZYAR.png

What I want to obtain is the last information namely "Sonic le film" from strong section, at this moment my code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.villedieu-cinema.fr/'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.txt, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': ' mceEditable'})
contents = table.find_all('tr')
```

Do you have some idea how to take this data? Big thanks for any tips!

Comment: You probably could try something like ```contents.html.find('a')[0].text```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL with the table is `https://www.villedieu-cinema.fr/semaine-2020-8-au-14-07-1/`.

You can use this example to get information from the table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.villedieu-cinema.fr/semaine-2020-8-au-14-07-1/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

movies = []
for tr in soup.select('.mceEditable tr'):
    tds = [' '.join(td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ').split()) for td in tr.select('td')]
    if tds[0]:
        movies.append(tds[0])
    print(tds)

# print all movies:
print()
print(*movies, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
['', 'Mer 8', 'Jeu 9', 'Ven 10', 'Sam 11', 'Dim 12', 'Lun 13', 'Mar 14']
['Sonic le film', '16h', '18h', '16h', '', '', '', '']
['Les parfums', '21h', '', '21h', '18h', '18h', '21h', '']
['Radioactive', '', '21h VO', '', '21h VF', '', '', '21h VF']

Sonic le film
Les parfums
Radioactive
```